# preg_replace with a word in an array

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to use certain words in a array called `keywords`, which will be used to be replaced in a string by "as".

```
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($this->keywords[$this->lang]); $i++)
    {
        $word = $this->keywords[$this->lang][$i];
        $a = preg_replace("/\b$word\b/i", "as",$this->code);
    }
```

It works with if I replace the variable `$word` with something like `/\bhello\b/i`, which then would replace all hello words with "as".

Is the approach am using even possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? If it works then it's definitely possible :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before to be a pattern, it's a double quoted string, so variables will be replaced, it's not the problem.

The problem is that you use a loop to change several words and you store the result in `$a`:

- the first iteration, all the occurences of the first word in `$this->code` are replaced and the new string is stored in `$a`.
- but the next iteration doesn't reuse `$a` as third parameter to replace the next word, but always the original string `$this->code`

Result: after the for loop `$a` contains the original string but with only the occurences of the last word replaced with `as`.

When you want to replace several words with the same string, a way consists to build an alternation: `word1|word2|word3...`. It can easily be done with `implode`:

```
$alternation = implode('|', $this->keywords[$this->lang]);

$pattern = '~\b(?:' . $alternation . ')\b~i';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, 'as', $this->code);
```

So, when you do that, the string is parsed only once and all the words are replaced in one shot.

---

If you have a lot of words and a very long string:

Testing a long alternation has a significant cost. Even if the pattern starts with `\b` that highly reduces the possible positions for a match, your pattern will have hard time to succeed and more to fail.

Only in this particular case, you can use this another way:

First you define a placeholder (a character or a small string that can't be in your string, lets say `§`) that will be inserted in each positions of word boundaries.

```
$temp = preg_replace('~\b~', '§', $this->code);
```

Then you change all the keywords like this `§word1§`, `§word2§` ... and you build an associative array where all values are the replacement string:

```
$trans = [];
foreach ($this->keywords[$this->lang] as $word) {
    $trans['§' . $word . '§'] = 'as';
}
```

Once you have do that you add an empty string with the placeholder as key. You can now use the fast `strtr` function to perform the replacement:

```
$trans['§'] = '';
$result = strtr($temp, $trans);
```

The only limitation of this technic is that it is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you keep it like bellow:

$a = preg_replace("/\b".$word."\b/i", "as",$this->code);

Comment: What's the difference? The string in the question is enclosed in double quotes, PHP [parses it for variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). It works.

Comment: There is nothing different from what you just wrote to what I have. All you have done is concatenate a string with another.